# iText incorrectly renders custom lato font

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

To register my custom lato font I use this method: `PdfFontFactory.register`. Afterwards I print out all fonts to verify it gets registered.

Then I use the font like so

```
setFont(PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("lato-regular"))
```

However there are very subtle differences in the display using the same ttf file on my website vs my pdf.

For example, the dot above the "i" is not circular but more of a rectangle with rounded edges when using iText.  Any ideas?

Comment: iText doesn't invent fonts, either you have the right font or the font was not found and was substituted. What does the reader tab says about the fonts used?

Comment: If I go to properties ->fonts I see

Comment: If it's there the font is used. Maybe it's an artifact of the reader. Please post the pdf for inspection.

Comment: Ah, Adobe was using it's default Seriff MM font since I forgot to embed mine.  It's working now.  Thanks!